# How to determine if a set is closed under some operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

> Is the set $\{-2,0,2\}$ closed under addition?  And why?

Specifically, when determining if a set is closed under an operation do you apply the operation to the each number and itself?

For example:
$2+2 = 4$ would make the set not closed vs
$-2+0 = -2$,
$-2+2 = 0$ would make the set closed.

Comment: I suggest not using "open" as an antonym of "closed" in mathematical writing. It leads to confusion when the concepts turn out to not be antonyms.

Comment: OK, now that I understand the definition, can someone please tell me the point of algebraic closures is? What are they used for? What questions do they answer? What is their application? ect. Thank you.

Comment: If a set is all you have, then its closure with respect to some binary operation amounts to your ability to perform this operation. If it's not closed, the operation ends up being undefined at times, and that is rather unpleasant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no notion of "set open under addition", only closed. A set is closed under some operation if applying the operation on *any* elements of the set gives an element which is still in that set. One counter-example is sufficient to show that the operation is not closed. $2+2 = 4 \notin \{-2,0,2\}$ shows that the operation $+$ is not closed on the set $\{-2,0,2\}$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

The set is not closed under addition as $2+2=4$ which is not in your set.. unless your addition is modulo $4$.